# Filtered Aggregation returns no results

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to replicate [filtered aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) on an example below:
Here, I'm trying to filter documents that match the name of a pipeline and find the maximum duration to execute among those pipelines.

```
{
    "_source" : {"excludes": ["stderr"]},
    "aggs" : {
        "max_duration_filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "term": {
                        "pipeline": "{name_of_pipeline}"
                }
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "max_duration" : {
                        "max" : {
                                "field" : "duration"
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calling this returns the following output along with 1 hit (I also passed in size=1)

```
{
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 63643,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "{name-of-index}",
        "_type" : "raw_data",
        "_id" : "{an-id}",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "duration" : 42.8,
          "pipeline" : "{a-different-pipeline}",
          "buildNumber" : {build-number-integer}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "max_duration_filtered" : {
      "doc_count" : 0,
      "max_duration" : {
        "value" : null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would really like some insight into why the max duration value is null. It seems that I mirrored what was in the docs pretty carefully. Is there anything I can try to fix the issue?
Thanks!

Comment: doc_count is 0, It means name you are filtering on is not present in  query result

Comment: Your filter doesn't work on the hits but only on the aggregations. Can you explain what you expect in the results?

Comment: @jaspreetchahal -> I made sure to check this by querying =>
```
{
 "_source" : {"excludes": ["stderr"]},
 "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }, 
    "size": 40
}
```
and found the name of the pipeline in the data

Comment: @Val I have data that contains a list of pipelines and the corresponding time they took to execute. 
I'm trying to filter the data by type of pipeline and then find the maximum amount of time taken by any of those pipelines to execute.
Basically filter by pipeline name and then find max duration among the filtered set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query would give you the max duration for each pipeline. No need to filter by a specific pipeline.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "pipeline.keyword": "some-pipeline"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "pipelines": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "pipeline.keyword",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_duration": {
          "max": {
            "field": "duration"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion!
I did run into an error with this though
```
 {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [pipeline] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
      }
```

Comment: Further, I was looking to stick to the filter + agg approach because I'd like to eventually filter by multiple fields and aggregate max duration on the filtered set.

Comment: Fixed my answer, please check it out again

Comment: If you want to stick to the filter, you should probably move that to the query section and not in the aggregations one. See my answer

Comment: Oh my god! It worked! :D Thanks a bunch Val! I have accepted your answer. Thanks again!
Can I get rid of the terms section in aggs now that I'm filtering in the query section?

Comment: I removed it and it worked! You're a lifesaver. Thanks again.